# Implementing Search Functionality

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary, uisearchcontroller

hello I have implemented an auto complete search on my app. I have cities stored in my mysql database and in app when user types any character or word, the app fetches result from the database and shows it. Now there is a small programming problem I am having and I don't know how to solve it.

The problem is in the same Array in which I am getting a City, I am getting country name and state name as well. As I have implemented a search only on cities not on state and country, I actually need the other columns(state,country) of those rows which are displaying based on user search city. I'll paste the code here for better understanding

```
class  CityTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var dict = NSDictionary()
    var filterTableData = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()


    var newTableData = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        self.resultSearchController = ({

            let controller  = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller


        })()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        if(self.resultSearchController.active){

            return self.filterTableData.count
        }else {

            return dict.count
        }



    }



        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CountryTableViewCell

            if(self.resultSearchController.active){

                cell.cityNameLabel.text = filterTableData[indexPath.row]

                cell.countryNameLabel.text =  get the country name

                 cell.stateNameLabel.text =  get stateName
                return cell

            }else{

                cell.cityNameLabel.text = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
                return cell
            }



        }

        func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
            filterTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            let searchWord = searchController.searchBar.text!

            getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord)

            let searchPredict = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
            print("searchPredict is \(searchController.searchBar.text!)")

            for var i = 0; i < self.dict.count; i++ {
                let cityName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String

         let countryName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String

let stateName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["State"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
            newTableData.append(cityname)
            }

            let array = (newTableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredict)
            print("array is\(array)")
            filterTableData = array as! [String]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }






        func getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord:String){


            let url:String = "http://localhost/"
            let params = ["city":searchWord]



            ServerRequest.postToServer(url, params: params) { result, error in

                if let result = result {
                    print(result)

                    self.dict = result

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

If I try to setup new array of state and country then data doesn't shows up correctly. cities don't belong to his own state shows up. So How I can keep the order correctly.

Array:

**dict**

```
 0 =     {
        City =         {
            code = 10430;
            "country_id" = 244;
            id = 8932;
            name = Laudium;
            "state_id" = 4381;
            "updated_at" = "<null>";
        };
        Country =         {
            id = 244;
            name = "South Africa";
        };
        State =         {
            "country_id" = 244;
            id = 4381;
            name = Gauteng;
        };
    }; etc
```

**newTableData**

`["Lynnwood", "Lyndhurst", "Laudium"]` etc

**filterTableData**

```
["Laudium", "La Lucia", "Lansdowne"] etc
```

Comment: Could you show how look like the data inside your array exactly?

Comment: okay do you want to see the original data which is in dictionary or you want to see the filtertabledata array ? could you tell me the variable name from the code ? @Larme

Comment: One object (not whole array) of each one could be interesting.

Comment: @Larme I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search the dictionary for the matches and store the matched keys in an array and reference to these keys in the results.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    let searchWord = searchController.searchBar.text!

    getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord)

    self.filteredKeys.removeAll()

    for (key, value) in self.dict {
        let valueContainsSearchWord: Bool = (((value as? NSDictionary)?["City"] as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as? String)?.uppercaseString.containsString(searchWord.uppercaseString) ?? false
        if valueContainsSearchWord {
            self.filteredKeys.append(key as! String)
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Fill the tableview with this filtered keys:
    let key = self.filteredKeys[indexPath.row]

```
let dictionary = self.dict[key] as! NSDictionary

cell.cityNameLabel.text = ((dictionary["City"] as? NSDictionary)!["name"] as? NSString)! as String

cell.countryNameLabel.text = ((dictionary["Country"] as? NSDictionary)!["name"] as? NSString)! as String

cell.stateNameLabel.text = ((dictionary["State"] as? NSDictionary)!["name"] as? NSString)! as String

return cell
```

Just save this filtered dictionary (self.filteredDictionary) and use that to populate the tableView.

I think the other problem is, when you call the server's search method (`getCityNamesFromServer:`) from `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` the response from the server comes asynchronously and the process afterwards is using the old dictionary data, because the new one is not ready at the time of the processing.

You should try modifying the `getCityNamesFromServer:` method with a block completion like this:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    // Get search word    
    getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord) { () -> Void in
            // Rest of the code comes here
    }
}
func getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord:String, completionHandler: (() -> Void) ) {
    let url:String = "http://localhost/"
    let params = ["city":searchWord]

    ServerRequest.postToServer(url, params: params) { result, error in

        if let result = result {
            print(result)

            self.dict = result

        }
        completionHandler()
   }

}
```

Comment: I think you haven't understood my problem clearly? @Kádi

Comment: It might be, sorry if I misunderstood but it still could be a problem. What is the main problem? I found this in your code and did not continue the reading.

Comment: no problem.. okay the issue is I don't know how I can save the reference of other variables. I mean see the result which is coming from server not only getting the cities. it has also cities, countries and state names. on the tableview when user searches the citiies I want to show the state and country name with city as well. How can I do that.

Comment: you understandwhat I am saying ? Its becoming very hard to explain ?

Comment: So you have the dict dictionary, search in city names and if a city name matches, you want to show the state and country of the city too?

Comment: yes exactly. Lets say user types the "laho" and if there are 3 cities starting from "laho" then my program will show those cities but I want to show their state and country as well. I think you got it. I just repeat it for you to understand better

Comment: I modified my answer, starting with the result you are searching.

Comment: could you please modified my question. Okay now if I want to print the country and city name  here  how would I do that if(self.resultSearchController.active){

                cell.cityNameLabel.text = filterTableData[indexPath.row]

                cell.countryNameLabel.text =

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104452/discussion-between-kadi-and-hellosheikh).